# MP Android Chart Multiple Y Axis In A Line Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Im trying to create a project that shows a combined value of data with different value types displayed in a line graph using MP Android chart. I would like to ask is it possible to create a line chart with multiple Y Axis for each values? like the picture below.

[image: graph with multiple y axis]

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I am in the same situation. I don't want to build custom chart.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation says that you can achieve it using `CombinedChart`:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java

Comment: The problem is that in the LineChart the Y-Axis gets scaled to the highest value of the graphs. But i kinda hoped to have multiple Y-Axis for each graph, so that everything gets scaled how it is required.

Comment: @Alex Kuzmin Are you sure this is possible? I have seen just Left and right Y axis. How do I add multiple?